# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync CancellationToken not working

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Has anyone ever been able to get the CancellationToken working for AuthorizeAsync()?

The following works:

```
private void TryToAuthenticate()
{
  //Cancel the task BEFORE it starts
  m_cancelTokSrc.Cancel();

  //Start task
  Task<UserCredential> task = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    scopes,
    "user",
    m_cancelTokSrc.Token,
    new FileDataStore(m_CredentialFilePath, true))
    .ContinueWith((t) => AuthenticateCompleted(t));
}

private UserCredential AuthenticateCompleted(Task<UserCredential> task)
{
  //FIRES JUST FINE!
  UserCredential credentials = null;
  switch (task.Status)
  {
    case TaskStatus.Canceled:
      return null;
    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
      credentials = task.Result;
      break;
  }

  return credentials;
}
```

The following does NOT work:

```
private void TryToAuthenticate()
{
  //Start task
  Task<UserCredential> task = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    scopes,
    "user",
    m_cancelTokSrc.Token,
    new FileDataStore(m_CredentialFilePath, true))
    .ContinueWith((t) => AuthenticateCompleted(t));

  //Cancel the task AFTER it starts
  m_cancelTokSrc.Cancel();
}

private UserCredential AuthenticateCompleted(Task<UserCredential> task)
{
  //DOES NOT FIRE!!!
  UserCredential credentials = null;
  switch (task.Status)
  {
    case TaskStatus.Canceled:
      return null;
    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
      credentials = task.Result;
      break;
  }

  return credentials;
}
```

It seems like whenever I request the authorization it just hangs waiting for a response from the web browser or something.  In the loop it has waiting for the authorization reply it seems to never check for  `cancelTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested`.  Has anyone ever successfully canceled the request?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I've searched more and this is the only question on this problem.

Comment: I don't think so...  I would have posted the answer.  It's been so long now.  I think I just shelved the project...  :/  Sorry bud.